# Get key from scan code for CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am able to capture the keys for ckeditor using following code

```
    CKEDITOR.instances.<ID of Control>.on('key', function (e) {
                e.data.keyCode ;//Gives scan code for keys ".,/;'\" ``
}
```

But  `e.data.keyCode` or if I handle "KeyUP" and "KeyDown" events with use of `evt.data.getKey()` I am able to get scan code of keys not the `charcode`.

It is required to detect char not scan code of key , please suggest me any mechanism to get `char`.
Working of `CKEDITOR.instances.<ID of Control>.on('key',...)` function handler is different from normal keypress event handler mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the char code is (for whatever I tried it's been `0`), but here's code that can help you:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        contentDom: function( evt ) {
            var editable = evt.editor.editable();
            editable.attachListener( editable, 'keyup', function( evt ) {
                console.log( 'getKey', evt.data.getKey() );
                console.log( 'getKeystroke', evt.data.getKeystroke() );
                console.log( 'native event', evt.data.$ );
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```

I assume that you're using CKEditor 4 and that code may not work on CKEditor 3.

I attached `keyup` event listener to editable. Editable is the main editable element - in inline editor it's a container on which editor was built and on framed editor this is `body` of an internal iframe.

Very important is to add this listener on `contentDom` event - it's fired every time content DOM is loaded and for framed editor that happen after every `setData` call (so pretty often). In framed editor `setData` creates completely new DOM, so it's important to remove old listeners attached to old DOM. This is handled by editable itself, but listener has to be attached by `attachListener` method.

Back to the question - I think that CKEditor doesn't provide a way to get char code. You need to use native event which is under `evt.data.$`.